# Как продлить срок действия пароля и где следить за его актуальностью?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Давно как-то ставил Oracle 11 себе на виртуальную машину. А сегодня понадобилось работать опять с системой. Попытался подключиться, но мне говорят срок действия пароля истек на пользователя `system`.

Как можно исправить эту проблему? Где надо продлевать пароль и следить за его актуальностью?

Comment: с локальной машины можно всегда зайти под встроеной учетной записью системного администратора (as sysdba):  https://community.oracle.com/thread/347053

Comment: а что с учетными записями пользователей? Мне нужно через system зайти, а не лишь бы только зайти в базу.

Comment: а дальше как-то так:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm

Comment: @jmu, то что вы указали в первом сообщение будет работать для 11g? Не поверю что в оракле такая дыра была, чтобы без пароля входить под админом... гранты и привилегии временные что ли? Почему пароли устаревают? Вопросы без ответов.

Comment: @IntegralAL а почему это дыра ?

Comment: @eicto, потому что любой злоумышленник может сесть за компьютер админа и заменить пароли юзеров, или права привилегии добавить какие-нибудь кому не надо, это про недобросовестных коллег, младшего звена можно сказать)).  А так за совет @jmu спасибо все сделал как указали, заработало, вошел в систему и настроил заново гранты и юзеров. Сделайте ответом свой коммент, и поставлю вам как верный ответ.

Comment: > Не поверю что в оракле такая дыра была, чтобы без пароля входить под админом...

проблема не в том что системный администратор может войти в субд а в в этом:

> потому что любой злоумышленник может сесть за компьютер админа

если вы не можете защитить пк от злоумышленника парится по поводу пароля на субд бесполезно

Answer (score 2):

Надо зайти на сервер БД под уч. записью, входящей в группу администраторов БД,
обычно `dba` (на Windows `ORA_DBA`). Если на сервере несколько инстанций БД, то надо убедится, что переменные окружения `ORACLE_SID`, `ORACLE_HOME` установлены правильно.

Зайти в SQL*Plus, посмотреть, у кого истёк пароль, продлить его (по умолчанию на 180 дней):

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba   

SQL> select username, account_status, lock_date, expiry_date
   2 from dba_users where account_status like 'EXPIRED%';

USERNAME         ACCOUNT_STATUS   LOCK_DATE       EXPIRY_DATE
---------------- ---------------- --------------- ---------------
ANONYMOUS        EXPIRED & LOCKED 20190417T020418 20190417T020418
HR               EXPIRED & LOCKED 20200615T202643 20200615T202643

SQL> alter user hr identified by hr account unlock;

User altered.
```